# MessageBox.Show() Error

Tags: vb.net

The message box should display "The sum of the numbers 1 through 10 is 55." So I have to put two variables in a message box. like this one

```
MessageBox.Show("Sum of Numbers", "The sum of numbers 1 through " & intUserInput.ToString, " is " & dblTotal.ToString, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
```

but I'm getting an error - "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Show' can be called with these arguments"

Not sure if I understands why.

Comment: what programming language is this? C# or VB? using the visual studio tag doesn't tell us much as that's only an IDE...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. This is VB

Comment: that is not VB code.   MsgBox(Params) is how you call a messagebox in VB - down voted both answers below as they are C# code not VB

Comment: @Sorceri VBA is not the same as VB

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's going on.  There's already a couple good posted answers, but basically what it's telling you is that the method is expecting a different number of arguments than what you're passing to it.

Comment: @user1666620 that was a typo and either way that is still not how you call a mesagebox in VB

Comment: Besides the missplaced comma, you have the message and the title reversed.

Comment: @Sorceri - the question is tagged as vb.net now.  This is how it's done in .NET (although I think the  VBA method still works as well).

Comment: @Sorceri i believe that the OP means vb.net and not simply VB. If it was VB, I'm pretty sure the the OP wouldn't experience the error they are getting.

Comment: Yea, I realized that the message and title were reversed. I fixed it along with comma error. Thank you everyone. It is resolved. :)

Comment: Well, I'm confused about VB or VB.net because I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. I was taught as Visual Basic so is that VB.net or something else?

Comment: What you're working with is very clearly .NET code.  There's another older technology that's referred to simply as VB script or VBA that's similar in a lot of ways (and in fact what VB.NET was built upon), but doesn't have support for some of the more modern things (use of MessageBox being one of the many things that's not supported).

Comment: @Sorceri - Also as a side note, this is in no way C# code.  C# uses `;` as a line delimiter between lines of code (or sometimes curly braces, depending on what you're doing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your string concatenation - try the below

```
MessageBox.Show("The sum of numbers 1 through " & intUserInput.ToString & " is " & dblTotal.ToString, "Sum of Numbers", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
```

There was a comma after the `intUserInput.ToString` portion, which looked like a new parameter argument.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma after ToString: intUserInput.ToString, " is "